# Translating SXA Date Filter

Tags: sxa, multilingual

[image]I'm using SXA 1.7 and i use a date range filter on a page.When i create an arabic version for this filter, i'm only allowed to translate the (Title, from label and  to label)but for example the month dropdown menu is always displayed in english as (Jan, Feb, Mar,.....) ,However i need to translate the displayed calendar itself. Is there a way to do so??[image]

Comment: Strange! Had a similar issue with event date, but my dates were translated to Georgian calendar. well did you try translating the months and days? by creating the Arabic version?

Comment: @Sitecore Sam  how can i translate the months and days?? i already created an arabic version for the Date filter but i don't know how to translate the months and days. i was only able to translate the title and labels.